# what is multipoint line configuration?

Tags: ethernet

i want to know what is multipoint line configuration and according to that is in ring network topology the link between two devices considered point to point or multipoint configuration ?

Comment: Sadly school work is off-topic

Comment: i want to know what is multipoint line configuration as i found that point to point the link is dedicated between two devices only while in multipoint the link can be shared between many devices , then considering four devices connected in ring topology if e.g. pc-1 want to send data to pc-3 the link between pc-1 and pc-2 will share data to pc-3 so we should consider it as multipoint link although in textbooks they considered these links as point to point !!!

Comment: Did any answer help you? if so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct that in a ring topology, the links between devices are point to point.  In a multipoint configuration, each device can directly communicate with another without an intermediary device.  In your question, when pc-1 sends data to pc-3, it must go through pc-2.  So it is not a multipoint connection.

Sometimes these terms can have multiple meanings, depending on the context.